# Correct way to check if object has the content property

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance

I need to check if an object has the Content property. This object can be anything: a Button, a Panel, a Grid, a Page, a ContentControl or a TextBlock.

I was checking in this way:

```
if (obj is ContentControl)
{
    // Yes
}
else
{
    // No
}
```

The problem is that I'm not sure if this is correct. Looking in MSDN, I see that the Page class contains the "Content" property, but it doesn't inherit from ContentControl. I'am right?

So, what is the correct way to check if a Control has the Content property?

Comment: the real question is what do you want this for. Unless you're creating an `Attached Property` or `Behavior` there is little need for such thing.

Comment: Let's say you have some random object that happens to have a property named `Content`, but that property isn't used in the same way a `Button` or other control uses it. The name of the property doesn't tell you anything about what that property is for. If something descends from `ContentControl`, it's pretty certain what that property will be used for.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether a property exists:

```
      var propInfo = obj.GetType ().GetProperty ("Content");
      if (propInfo != null)
      {
         //the propery exists
      }
```